# Best photo tour to Cuba?

Tags: travel

I'm looking for a photo tour to Cuba/ Any recommendations for groups or tour operators? I'm a U.S. citizen, which makes it slightly tricky, but not too bad given the recent changes in regulations. Mostly, I want to be part of a

Comment: Part of a ... ?

Comment: obviously "they" found out he was going to Cuba and stopped him!

Comment: I see that this is getting "too localized" close votes. Remember, just because it has _a location_ doesn't mean _too_ localized. Cuba attracts over two million tourists in a year; that's a bigger audience than that for many of our specific technical questions. (Meta discussion [here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63/photo-location-tips-on-or-off-topic/1232#1232)).

Comment: Mattdm is correct...just because a question has a location does not necessarily mean it is too localized. A question is too localized when it doesn't serve a large enough audience. Full details can be found at the meta discussion @mattdm linked.

Comment: Cuba itself is NOT too localized, I've been there. While I do not lead tours there, a friend did and stopped, it involved too much trouble convincing Cuban immigration that entering all that photography gear (10 or so people with 2-3 cameras each) in the country was NOT for journalistic reasons. Some arrived in Cuba but were not let in. I agree with Jrista this question does not serve a broad audience and the probability of a US photographer wanting to go to Cuba on tour is too low.

Comment: Strongly disagree w/ @Itai saying "the probability of a US photographer wanting to go to Cuba on tour is too low".  I know several photographers who have done that and several more who want to.

Comment: @Itai - I don't think thats what jrista said...   He said that was the definition of a too localized, not that *this question* was too localized.  As its stands now its just an incomplete questi